# Find if there's at least one - Observable Java 8 Rx

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, rx-java

I have an `Observable<SomeObject>` for which I need to test that there's at least one element of value "thing" (not a stream, I suppose) respecting a condition (it's for a unit test, so I'd need to assert something or at the very least throw an exception). How should I write this in Java 8?

To better explain:

```
Observable<SomeObject> thing = someFunction();
thing.flatMap(c -> c.toObservable())
.filter(q -> someContidion(q))
.forEach(x -> Assert.assertTrue(x!=null));
```

Of course this is not what I need, since if there is no element matching the condition I don't see any error and the unit test passes.

Comment: [`stream.anyMatch(predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

Comment: no sorry, my question was non-accurate and I can't still find a way to use anyMatch (maybe it's correct, but if I try to use it after flatMap it says cannot resolve method)

Comment: Observable is from RxJava, you can use the `exists()` method or if you want a terminal operation like `stream.anyMatch(predicate)` in Java you can use something like `exists().toBlockingObservable().single()`

Comment: Thank you @NickVanderhoven , that is what I needed, for whatever reason the question has been changed back to remove the details.

Comment: @t-rossi sometimes, Stack Overflow is Sparta

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use what the RxJava project uses already for its own test cases, which is [`TestSubscriber`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html) ([`TestScheduler`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/schedulers/TestScheduler.html) may also prove to be useful to you at some point):

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class RxTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Observable<String> thing = Observable.just("thing", "stuff", "whatever", "", null);
        Observable<Boolean> test = thing.contains("thing");

        TestSubscriber<Boolean> sub = new TestSubscriber<>();
        test.subscribe(sub);

        sub.assertValue(true);
    }
}
```